# Missing free space on partition with Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've just realized that on my C: partition, which has capacity of 111GB, I have a GB of free space missing:

- 111GB - capacity of my SSD drive
- 69,7 GB free of 111GB - this is what My Computer info is saying about my C:
- when I go to C:, and select all files and run Properties, the size in only 15,9GB

So where are my 25GB of free space missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all files are selected by default in Windows Explorer. As an example, the Page File and Hibernation file, both of which are 1-2x the amount of RAM you have in your system. When you right-click and go to Properties of the hard drive, it includes all the hidden and system files as well

Comment: Correct! I've just came across http://www.downloadbestsoft.com/WinDirStat.html - it shows all files